# constructing an example of a ball of larger radius, contained in a ball of smaller radius

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I've found an example where there is a ball of larger radius contained in a ball of smaller radius, but I'm not sure how it works:

Let $X = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq 9 \}$ with the Euclidean distance. Consider:

$$B((0,0),3) = X$$
$$ B((2,0),4) = \{ x \in X: (x_1 -2)^2 + x_2^2 \leq 16 \}$$

Apparently this gives $B((2,0),4) \subset B((0,0),3)$ but I'm not exactly sure how. Any explanation please

Comment: This is not true. $B((2, 0), 4)$ contains $(4, 0)$ but $B((0, 0), 3)$ does not.

Comment: @MartinR it stated it in my book, that's why I asked because I didn't understand how it gave it.

Comment: @MartinR I don't think I quoted it wrong, and I'm not sure how Travis's counter-example is a counter example as $x = (4,0)$ is not in $X$

Comment: why did you remove your comment?

Comment: @Travis could you please read the above comments and explain how your example is a counter-example?

Comment: @DH. Ah, i see the problem now: The second set is not a ball, but rather the intersection of two balls. It's awfully misleading to denote this set by $B((2, 0), 4)$ (as someone might read this, assume this is the usual ball notation, consistent with $B((0, 0), 3)$, and not read the definition of the set, which is precisely what I did). This intersection is indeed in $X$ (in fact, for all sets $A, B$, $A \cap B \subseteq B$).

Comment: @DH.: I removed my comment because I noticed that the second definition  is restricted to $x \in X$, I had overlooked that before, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

This question is messed up, but not for the reasons given above.

The metric space $X$ is the entire closed disk of radius 3 centered at the origin. So points outside this disk simply ***don't exist*** (for the duration of this problem).

The ball $B((0,0),3)$ is then the interior of this ball and contains all the points in the disk (but not on the boundary of the disk).

The ball $B((2,0), 4)$ is perfectly well defined and it is the set of points **that are in $X$** that have distance up to $4$ from $(2,0)$. This ball is not contained in $B((0,0),3)$ though, because $(3,0)$ is in $B((2,0),4)$ but not in $B((0,0),3)$ [remember that a ball contains all the points whose distance from the centre is **less than** the radius].

So let's make the first ball a bit bigger, say $B((0,0), 3.5)$ and now every point in $X$ is in this ball, and so definitely 
$$
B((2,0),4) \subseteq B((0,0),3.5)
$$

But we notice that the point $(-3,0)$ lies in $X$, but not in $B((2,0),4)$ (because the distance from $(2,0)$ to $(-3,0)$ is 5). So we have 
$$
B((2,0),4) \subset B((0,0),3.5)
$$

The commenters above who said things like "the set is not a ball" are assuming that the underlying universe is $\mathbb{R}^2$ where balls are circular shapes. But as soon as you change the underlying set or the underlying metric, balls can have all sorts of weird shapes.

Answer (score 1):

The statement $B((2,0),4)\subseteq B((0,0),3)$ is not true. Take the point $(6,0)$ for example. Then $(6-2)^2 = 16$, thus $(6,0)\in B((2,0),4)$. However $6^2=36\nleq 9$, thus $(6,0)\notin B((0,0),3)$.

Comment: We have that $B((2,0),4) = \{ x \in X: (x_1-2)^2 + x_2^2 \leq 16\}$ the example you gave was $x = (6,0)$ but $(6,0) \notin X$ so it isn't a valid counter example

Comment: Yes it is, calculate the formula with $x_1 = 6$ and $x_2 = 0$, then $(6-2)^2+0^2 = 4^2 = 16 \le 16$.

Comment: $(6,0)$ is not in $X$ because elements in $X$ have to satisfy $x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq 9$, and $6^2 \not \leq 9$

Comment: Oh now I get it.... Sorry, my bad for reading it wrong. Your second set is restricted to any $x\in X$, thus therefore it belongs to $X$. However, your second set is not a ball of radius 4. It is the intersection of two balls. One of radius 4 around $(2,0)$ and one of radius $3$ around $(0,0)$. Therefore the notation $B((2,0),4)\cap B((0,0),3)$ might be a better notation for your second set.

Comment: But that intersection wouldn't give a ball of radius $>3$ right? Then this example doesn't prove what I'm asking, which is to find a ball of a larger radius contained in a ball of smaller radius

Comment: Exactly. The second set is not a ball. Also, what you are trying to prove is not possible.

Comment: Of course $(6,0)$ is not in $X$. That is what @Marc is saying, the ball with radius 4  IS NOT contained in the ball X.